# What's the equivalent "sizeWithFont: " method for the Mac?

Tags: macos, nsstring, size, nstextview

I'm familiar with `sizeWithFont:`  for the iPhone. Now I'm trying to build an app for the Mac and need something like that, but I don't know how to do it :/

Here's why I need it: I've got a panel that displays some text, and I want to size it so that it just fits the content (a `NSTextView`). How would you do it?

Comment: @Bernardo: please don't rollback useful changes. You had a typo in the title and someone else was kind enough to fix that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at NSString's `sizeWithAttributes:`. You'll have to create a dictionary of attributes; take a look at [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/standardAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004903-SW2) for that.

Comment: But it doesn't seem to work well enough for me. Kindly take a look at my questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766189/how-do-we-measure-visible-bounds-of-text-in-cocoa/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877791/what-does-the-nsstringdrawingusesdevicemetrics-flag-mean-and-how-do-we-use-it and see if you can answer them.

Comment: Finally answered one of my questions (links in the previous comment). But anyway, I guess the question here just seems to be how to obtain the typographic bounds and not the visible bounds like I wanted.

Comment: @andyvn22 Can you confirm as of 2013 and Mavericks ?

Comment: You need to use both sizeWithAttributes as well as boundingRectWithSize, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033598/uikits-nsstring-sizewithfontconstrainedtosize-in-appkit/20556412#20556412