# UIKit's [NSString sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:] in AppKit

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, appkit

Is there any equivalent method in AppKit (for Cocoa on Mac OS X) that does the same thing as UIKit's `[NSString sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:]`?

If not, how could I go about getting the amount of space needed to render a particular string constrained to a width/height?

Update: Below is a snippet of code I'm using that I expect would produce the results I'm after.

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSFont systemFontOfSize: [NSFont smallSystemFontSize]], NSFontAttributeName,
                            [NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                            nil];
NSSize size = NSMakeSize(200.0, MAXFLOAT);
NSRect bounds;

bounds = [@"This is a really really really really really really really long string that won't fit on one line"
             boundingRectWithSize: size
             options: NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
             attributes: attributes];

NSLog(@"height: %02f, width: %02f", bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width);
```

I would expect that the output width would be 200 and the height would be something greater than the height of a single line, however it produces:

```
height: 14.000000, width: 466.619141
```

Thanks!

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349692/whats-the-equivalent-sizewithfont-method-for-the-mac. Doesn't anyone search these days?

Comment: I searched but, amazingly I didn't find that one.  Regardless, sizeWithAttributes: does not, afaik, support constraining the width.

Comment: This is not a duplicate because of the constraint element, which is missing from that other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** You should be able to do things the normal way in Lion and later. The problems described below have been fixed.

---

There is no way to accurately measure text among the current Mac OS X APIs.

There are several APIs that promise to work but don't. That's one of them; [Core Text's function for this purpose](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFramesetterRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints) is another. Some methods return results that are close but wrong; some return results that seem to mean nothing at all. I haven't filed any bugs on these yet, but when I do, I'll edit the Radar numbers into this answer. You should file a bug as well, and include your code in a small sample project.

[Apparently I have already filed the Core Text one: 8666756. It's closed as a duplicate of an unspecified other bug. For Cocoa, I filed 9022238 about the method Dave suggested, and will file two NSLayoutManager bugs tomorrow.]

[This is the closest solution I've found.](http://growl.info/hg/growl/file/ea025888c74a/Developer%20Tools/GrowlMailUUIDPatcher/source/GrowlMailUUIDPatcher.m#l296)

Comment: @PeterHosey You say it works on Lion but it doesn't seem to for me.. here's my question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766189/how-do-we-measure-visible-bounds-of-text-in-cocoa and a related question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877791/what-does-the-nsstringdrawingusesdevicemetrics-flag-mean-and-how-do-we-use-it/

Comment: @PeterHosey I'm sorry, I think I got carried away with my questions and didn't fully understand this question. So, this particular problem may have been solved in Lion. BTW, I solved one of my problems (links in the comment above) a couple of days back.

Answer (score 13):

Try this one:

```
bounds = [value boundingRectWithSize:size options:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping | NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes];
```

Comment: `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` is not an `NSStringDrawingOptions` option.  It is defined as 0 so it has no effect.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy 0 does not mean no effect, it means default.

Answer (score 6):

The newer NSExtendedStringDrawing category API (methods with the NSStringDrawingOptions argument) behaves in the single line mode. If you want to measure/render in multi line mode, want to specify NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin.

Comment: OMG! YES! This innocuous comment was what made `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:` magically work for me! `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin` is the important option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to constrain the string to a certain size, you use [`-[NSString boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000155-CJBJDCCE).  The `.size` of the returned `NSRect` is the size you're looking for.

Comment: I've added some code that I would expect to work in the question, but it clearly doesn't.  Would you mind pointing me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Comment: Agreed... this definitely doesn't seem to work, not sure why.

Comment: As Aki helpfully mentioned, you need to specify the `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin` option for multi-line calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more complete example of how you can do this using boundingRectWithSize.

```
// get the text field
NSTextField* field = (NSTextField*)view;

// create the new font for the text field
NSFont* newFont = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:11.0];

// set the font on the text field
[field setFont:newFont];

// calculate the size the textfield needs to be in order to display the text properly
NSString* text      = field.stringValue;
NSInteger maxWidth  = field.frame.size.width;
NSInteger maxHeight = 20000;
CGSize constraint   = CGSizeMake(maxWidth, maxHeight);
NSDictionary* attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSFontAttributeName,newFont, nil];
NSRect newBounds    = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                         options:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping | NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                      attributes:attrs];

// set the size of the text field to the calculated size
field.frame = NSMakeRect(field.frame.origin.x, field.frame.origin.y, field.frame.size.width, newBounds.size.height);
```

Of course, for additional info, take a look at the Apple documentation:

- [Options for the attributes dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/standardAttributes.html)
- [boundingRectWithSize](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize%3aoptions%3aattributes%3a)

Answer (score -4):

If you search the documentation for `NSString`, you will find the "NSString Application Kit Additions Reference", which is pretty much analogous to the UIKit counterpart.

```
-[NSString sizeWithAttributes:]
```

is the method you are looking for.

Comment: Is there and attribute that tells sizeWithAttributes: to constrain its width/height?