# Change NSTextField's height according to Font/Size

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, size, nstextfield, nsfont

**Ok, here's my situation :**

- I've got an `NSTextField`, set up as **Multi-line Text Label**
- The `NSTextField` is supposed to be holding just ONE line of text (even if it's a multi-line one)
- The `NSTextField` has a **fixed height**.
- The **Font** and **Font Size** are changed by the user

**The issue :**

- Depending on the font used, and size, **the bottom part of the text goes missing** (as it goes beyond the `NSTextField`'s boundaries

**What I want :**

- Get the **Text height**, based on selection (Font & Font Size) and set the `NSTextField`'s height accordingly.

---

I know it may sound complicated, but I also know it CAN be done.

Any ideas? Any reference to point me to?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can take the size of the string and then change the height accordingly

```
NSString *text = // your string
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(210, 20000.0f);
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:14] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

UITextField *cellTextLabel = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 9, 230, size.height)];
cellTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
cellTextLabel.numberOfLines = 50;
cellTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cellTextLabel.text = text;
cellTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14];
[self.view addSubview:cellTextLabel];
[cellTextLabel release];
```

Comment: Is this (I mean its equivalent) valid for OS X, too?

Comment: OK, thanks buddy! Give me a minute to check this one out and I'll let you know...

Comment: sure.. do check n let me know.. if this doesnt work we can come up with something else

Comment: sizeWithFont only works in UIKit, in AppKit you should use boundingRectWithSize.  See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033598/uikits-nsstring-sizewithfontconstrainedtosize-in-appkit/20556412#20556412

Comment: This answer shouldn't have been marked as correct — NSTextField is not the same as UITextField. See the answer Scott linked to above for something that will work with NSTextField.

Answer (score 4):

As already said, NSTextField and UITextField are very different objects (contrary to what their name suggests). Specifically, for NSTextField you could use an elegant solution involving the NSLayoutManager. An NSLayoutManager object coordinates the layout and display of characters held in an NSTextStorage object. It maps Unicode character codes to glyphs, sets the glyphs in a series of NSTextContainer objects, and displays them in a series of NSTextView objects.

All that you need is to create a NSLayoutManager an NSTextContainer and an NSTextStorage. They wrap all together in a similar fashion:

```
.-----------------------.
|     NSTextStorage     | 
|  .-----------------.  |
|  | NSLayoutManager |  |
|  '-----------------'  |
|  | NSTextStorage   |  |
|  '-----------------'  |
|                       |
'-----------------------'
```

That said, you can use the layoutManager method `usedRectForTextContainer:` to estimate the correct size containing your desired text.

The following should work for your problem:

```
- (float)heightForStringDrawing:(NSString *)aString withFont:(NSFont *)aFont andWitdh:(float)myWidth
{
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:aString];
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithContainerSize:NSMakeSize(myWidth,CGFLOAT_MAX)];

    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    [layoutManager setTypesetterBehavior:NSTypesetterBehavior_10_2_WithCompatibility];
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

    [textStorage addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:aFont
                        range:NSMakeRange(0,[textStorage length])];
    [textContainer setLineFragmentPadding:0.0];

    NSRange glyphRange = [layoutManager glyphRangeForTextContainer:textContainer];
    [layoutManager drawGlyphsForGlyphRange: glyphRange atPoint:NSMakePoint(0, 0)];

    return [layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer].size.height;
}
```

There's an exhaustive Apple document about this topic:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/StringHeight.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001809-CJBGBIBB

Also, some veterans have dissected the problem on Apple Mailing List some times ago:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2006/Jan/msg01874.html

Answer (score 1):

As @valvoline said, this is working, however you get a lot of CGContext warnings like `CGContextGetFontRenderingStyle: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.` if you do this outside of drawRect. Best solution is to not use drawGlyphsForGlyphRange: as the apple Documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/StringHeight.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001809-CJBGBIBB tells.