# How do we measure visible bounds of text in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, text, fonts

None of the methods listed below give the exact visible bounds of a text in Cocoa. How do we obtain that?

- `NSString`'s `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:`
- `NSAttributedString`'s `boundingRectWithSize:options:`
- `NSLayoutManager`'s `usedRectForTextContainer:`

To illustrate this, [here's a screenshot](http://ScrnSht.com/juixwk) of the result of using the second method above as shown in [this sample code snippet](http://pastebin.com/t38EceGT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I coded up. Any suggestions for improvements are most welcome.
code snippet: http://pastebin.com/qJMKwvau
screenshot: http://ScrnSht.com/jskyqs

Answer (score 4):

Actually, from the typographic point of view, the box is correct, but the font exceeds is own bound. You can try the option `NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics`, that uses  glyph bounds instead of typographic bounds.

Comment: Thanks. But, no luck with `NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics`. Got the same output. I'm not too sure what this bounds is useful for. Perhaps it is meant to be used for finding where to draw adjacent text on either of the four sides. But in my case I want the exact visible bounds and I've not been able to find a single way for obtaining that. Hoping that's possible. Any more ideas?

Comment: From the description of the flag it looks like exactly what I'm looking for but I just tested out to see if the flag makes a difference for any of the fonts on my system and it turns out it makes no difference at all whether included or omitted along with `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin`. Could it be a bug in Cocoa?!