# What does the NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics flag mean and how do we use it?

Tags: macos, cocoa, text, fonts

This question is in relation to my comment at [How do we measure visible bounds of text in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766189/how-do-we-measure-visible-bounds-of-text-in-cocoa#comment15682813_11766354).

Here are a couple of links explaining the meaning of the flag.
[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics)
[Apple lists answer to a similar question](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2006/Feb/msg00560.html)

From the above, I guess the option `NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics` is given for obtaining the visible bounds of text but it doesn't seem to do that. Among the inputs (font and string) I tried giving to the method `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:` none of the outputs were different when the flag was given compared to when the flag was not given. Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in Cocoa?

Thank you

Answer (score -3):

Google this monkey patch

NS(Attributed)String+Geometrics

It solves the problem fairly reliably.

Comment: Couldn't understand from the code at a glance. Will try it in a few days and get back. Thanks. Also, do you mean it is a bug in Cocoa?

Comment: The question is *what does this flag mean*. Dropping some random category into the program does not explain what that flag does.

Comment: @PeterHosey You're right. That would be an answer to my other question. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: @stackmonster I commented out the `NSLayoutManager (extra)` category (10 lines starting from http://git.io/oh98VQ ) which gave me a link error otherwise and didn't seem to be doing anything useful. It seemed to give the same output as shown in the website but this doesn't give the visible bounds either which can be seen when trying out for larger fonts. See http://ScrnSht.com/sakadu for a screenshot of what I get for Zapfino font in 48 pt for the text Zapfino. I tested it with Chalkduster as well and the bounds given is lesser than the visible bounds for that too.